# After installing my centOS 9 on my oracle VB. It works fine but once I power it off, I won’t be able to boot again. It just keep rotating endlessly

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, oracle-linux

The oracle virtual box was installed on my windows 10 with a 4gb ram.
When installing the centos9 I choose 2gm processor space and 20gb storage space.

Comment: Is `gm` supposed to be `mhz` or `gb`?  The rule of thumb is never give the vm more than half your RAM, and even 4GB is considered low for Windows 10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.